# getting org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException error

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

As mentioned above, I'm getting the exception mentioned above.

Can you please help? thanks

---

I've looked at various guides/tutorials and they don't really tell you what is the mapping required to run such examples. or The examples I've seen doesn't really have anything that involves retrieving data. It's mostly about insert/update and delete.

**an example from the jboss doc** (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html)

```
select foo
from Foo foo, Bar bar
where foo.startDate = bar.date
```

**This is my HQL:**

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Staff staff, Url url where (staff.id = url.id (+))");
```

This my mapping XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.flinders.staffdirectory.models.database.Staff" table="teld_summary">
        <id name="id" column="telsumm_id" type="string" />
        <property name="title" column="telsumm_name_title" type="string" />
        <property name="firstname" column="telsumm_preferred_name" type="string" />
        <property name="surname" column="telsumm_surname" type="string" />
        <one-to-one name="url" class="org.flinders.staffdirectory.models.database.Url" />
    </class>

    <class name="org.flinders.staffdirectory.models.database.Url" table="teld_urls">
        <id name="id" column="telurl_id">
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">staff</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="staff" class="org.flinders.staffdirectory.models.database.Staff" constrained="true" />
        <property name="url" column="url" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**my error**

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ) near line 1, column 142 [from org.flinders.staffdirectory.models.database.Staff staff, org.flinders.staffdirectory.models.database.Url url where (staff.id = url.id (+)) and (staff.surnameSearch like 'A%') order by surname, firstname]
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1735)
    org.flinders.staffdirectory.dao.StaffDAOImpl.searchForStaff(StaffDAOImpl.java:49)
    org.flinders.staffdirectory.services.SearchServiceImpl.searchForStaff(SearchServiceImpl.java:26)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy13.searchForStaff(Unknown Source)
    org.flinders.staffdirectory.controllers.SearchController.showSearchResults(SearchController.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

**my staff class**

```
package org.flinders.staffdirectory.models.database;

import java.util.Date;

import org.flinders.staffdirectory.models.database.Url;

public class Staff {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String firstname;
    private String surname;

    private Url url;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Url getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(Url url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

**my Url class**

```
package org.flinders.staffdirectory.models.database;

import org.flinders.staffdirectory.models.database.Staff;

public class Url {
    private String id;
    private String url;

    private Staff staff;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Staff getStaff() {
        return staff;
    }
    public void setStaff(Staff staff) {
        this.staff = staff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are using `(+)` in the query?

Comment: In your error `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ) near line 1, column 142 `  this indicate that there is something wrong with the `(+)` in you query.

Comment: Query in your exception and query you written above is different. Which one is correct ??

Comment: (+) is something I'm used to when righting Oracle queries :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to do a right join, remove the (+) and try

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Staff staff right join Url url where (staff.id = url.id)");
```

Comment: let me try that. thanks! :) what kind of object will I be getting as a result? I generic List<Object>? thank you again